# Slow Internet connection

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, internet

This is my first Q/A so i hope that will be clear.

While i checking my internet connection speed with my phone that shows me download speed of 30MB,And while i doing this with the ubuntu system that shows me download speed of 1.5-6MB...

Anyone can help me? i surely belive thats kind of drivers problem but i cant figure it out.

The `output of lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:0107  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: 6c:f0:49:76:12:6b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fbeff000-fbefffff memory:fbef8000-fbefbfff memory:fbb00000-fbb1ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlx503eaa9c1c6c
       serial: 50:3e:aa:9c:1c:6c
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.15.0-70-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.5 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

The output of `lsmod | grep rtl`:

```
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
mac80211              786432  1 rtl8xxxu
```

The `outpot of iwconfig`:

```
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    wlx503eaa9c1c6c  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"L***t."  
              Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: E4:6F:13:72:99:52   
              Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
              Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off
              Link Quality=16/70  Signal level=-94 dBm  
              Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
              Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:206   Missed beacon:0

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

The output of `dkms status`:

```
  nvidia-340, 340.107, 4.15.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily, 0.201905191531~ubuntu18.04.1, 4.15.0-69-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily, 0.201905191531~ubuntu18.04.1, 4.15.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.2.34, 4.15.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I Wish some one would help me to gain more download speed.

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `iwconfig`.

Comment: How are you connecting ? WiFi ? How far is the router and Ubuntu machine ?

Comment: Your wireless connection is very weak... weak to the point of getting disconnected. How far are you away from the wireless router/access point?

Comment: Yes i am connected with wireless-wifi the router is just in the next room,my xiomi phone reach an 30m download speed while the computer now reach only 1.5M,any seggestions?

Comment: Do you have `Access Control` or `QoS` enabled in your router? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Yes it is enabled it my router,should i Disable QoS in the router?

Comment: Yes. Although it won't help with your poor wireless connection, it may help solve a speed testing issue. For the poor wireless connection, you may have a situation where the wireless antenna is connected to the wrong terminal on the wireless card... but I can't help you with that. Desktop or laptop?

Comment: USB dongle, or internal PCI card?

Comment: @ heynnema - Desktop that connect with USB dongle(TL-WN821N)...I know that is not the best condition...

Comment: Did turning off QoS help with the speed testing? With an external USB wireless dongle, there's no *wrong* antenna wiring... that was only for internal cards. Remember to use @heynnema with no spaces. Thanks!

Comment: What driver are you using for the wireless dongle? Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Editted as you ask for,thank about the fast responding @heynnema

Comment: Did turning off QoS help with the speed testing?

Comment: @heynnema little bit kind of but the smartphone still gain way more power from the route...,from your eyes the drivers stuff look update and all?

Comment: If turning off QoS didn't really help, remember to enable it again. To eliminate a driver/software problem with your computer, please create a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 19.10. Boot to it, and see if wireless works any better.